# Consistent Encoding for iCal file import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, icalendar

I'm trying to use the iCalendar gem to import some iCal files on a rails 4 site.

Sometimes the file is of type '`text/calendar;charset=utf-8`' and sometimes its '`text/calendar; charset=UTF-8;`'

I am retrieving it like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
calendar = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
new_calendar = Icalendar.parse(calendar.body)
```

When its `text/calendar;charset=utf-8` it works fine. but when its `text/calendar; charset=UTF-8` encoded I get UTF codes in the string

```
SUMMARY:Tech Job Fair – City(ST) – Jul 1, 2015
```

ends up being

```
["Tech Job Fair \xE2\x80\x93 City(ST) \xE2\x80\x93 Jul 1", " 2015"]
```

Which is then saved to the database and that is undesirable.

Is the charset/content-type revealing the problem here or could it actually just be encoded wrong from the source?

**How do I change my retrieval commands to strip those codes out effectively or tell it its a UTF string so it doesn't include them in the first place?**

Update:  it looks like some are `text/calendar;charset=utf-8` and some are `text/calendar;charset=UTF-8` and some are `text/calendar; charset=UTF-8`. Note the last one has a space between the two segments. Could this be causing an issue?

Update2:  Opening up my three example iCal files in Notepad++ shows them encoded as "UTF-8 without BOM" in the menu.